# In vue, i want draw table by v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-for

Here is my js array.

```js
mydata:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And this is result what i want by table

> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9

in vanila html,

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

1,2,3... data is just sample. It can be string or other data type

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Since you want to wrap 3 `td`s into a `tr`, you will probably need to group your numbers into a smaller group. I guess that having `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` is a nice start. Then, apply some CSS to it. CSS grid or flexbox can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
<template>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="row in Math.floor(mydata.length/3)">
      <td v-for="col in 3">{{ mydata[(row-1)*3+(col-1)]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

Comment: good. I succeed in the above way, but I'll try this solution too. thanks